# I have Triggered Webjob which runs every midnight once, But its seems multiple instance are invoked which duplicates the task performed by them

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

**I have a WebJob as below.**

[image: WebJob list]

I deployed it via VSTS CICD pipeline.
It should ideally run 1 instance and send only 1 email and stop after that but it runs 2 instances and sends 2 emails like below. As it is a triggered job I was hoping only 1 instance would be invoked in Azure.

[image: Emails sent twice]

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Jason,  I cannot make the job as continous, it has other issues which comes if it is continous. So i have to keep it  as triggered. And with triggered i dont think we can have issingleton = true work for me, as this is only for continous jobs. Correct me in case i am wrong

Comment: I have update my answer, you can try it. If not works, you can raise a support ticket on portal.